# Не обратится к объекту в javafx

Tags: java, javafx

Хочу создать просто сервер с GUI на javafx.
Вот код:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.*;
import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Main extends Application {
    private Stage stage;
    private Scene scene;
    private AnchorPane pane;
    @FXML
    private TextArea area;

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception{
        this.stage = primaryStage;
        pane = (AnchorPane)FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("sample.fxml"));
        stage.setTitle("Server by nrjshka v0.1");
        scene = new Scene(pane, 600, 400);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();

        ** МЕСТО ХХХ**

    }

    @FXML
    public void initialize(){
        area.appendText("Server is started...\n");
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

В методе `initialize` я обращаюсь к `TextField`, чтобы добавить текст: `Server is started...\n`.
При попытке это сделать в другом месте(уже после парсинга из `.fxml` файла), например в месте ХХХ, выдает такую ошибку:

> Exception in Application start method
>   java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException   
> at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)   
> at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     
> at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     
> at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)     
> at
>   com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplicationWithArgs(LauncherImpl.java:389)
>     
> at
>   com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication(LauncherImpl.java:328)
>     
> at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>     
> at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     
> at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     
> at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)     
> at
>   sun.launcher.LauncherHelper$FXHelper.main(LauncherHelper.java:767)
>   Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception in Application start
>   method    
> at
>   com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(LauncherImpl.java:917)
>     
> at
>   com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication$155(LauncherImpl.java:182)
>     
> at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) Caused by:
>   java.lang.NullPointerException    
> at Server.Main.start(Main.java:26)
>     
> at
>   com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$162(LauncherImpl.java:863)
>     
> at
>   com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$175(PlatformImpl.java:326)
>     
> at
>   com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$null$173(PlatformImpl.java:295)
>     
> at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>     
> at
>   com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$174(PlatformImpl.java:294)
>     
> at
>   com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:95)
>     
> at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
>     
> at
>   com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$148(WinApplication.java:191)
>     ... 1 more Exception running application Server.Main

Comment: _При попытке это сделать в другом месте_ а где работает? И собственно, не увидел в коде как присваиваете к `TextArea area` объект `TextArea`

Comment: в твоём sample.fxml, должна быть ссылка на этот класс, как класс контроллера.

Comment: так ссылка делается, сказал же, что в методе initialize работает, а если вставлять тот же код в другой метод - то не будет работать!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вам нужно получить контроллер. И уже из него выполнять нужные методы. Поэтому в идеале стоит вынести его в отдельный класс.

Вот вам материал для изучения [Учебник по JavaFX 8 (Русский)](http://code.makery.ch/library/javafx-8-tutorial/ru/).

```
public class Main extends Application {

    private Stage primaryStage;
    private Scene scene;
    private AnchorPane pane;

    @FXML
    private Label serverInfo;

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        this.primaryStage = primaryStage;
        this.primaryStage.setTitle("q647269");
        FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
        loader.setLocation(getClass().getResource("root.fxml"));
        pane = (AnchorPane) loader.load();
        scene = new Scene(pane);
        this.primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        this.primaryStage.show();


        Main controller = loader.getController();
        controller.setInfo("server is started...");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    public void setInfo(String text) {
        serverInfo.setText(text);
    }

}
```

root.fxml

```
<AnchorPane maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="600.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="com.stackoverflow.ru.q647269.Main">
   <children>
      <Label fx:id="serverInfo" layoutX="14.0" layoutY="14.0" text="Label" />
   </children>
</AnchorPane>
```